# No valid fake msdos table

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, gparted

My PC contains a standard windows 8.1 installation. It recently crashed while I was in the middle of partitioning my drive with windows drive manager. As a result my computer now crashes with a BSOD:
`unmountable_boot_volume`

I've burned a bootable iso containing many recovery tools. A friend let me borrow it and I'm not sure what it is exactly. It appears to be some sort of mini linux OS:

[image]

Anyway, upon opening gparted within this linux distro, I get hit with this error message:
[image: no fake msdos table]

**No fake msdos table** That appears to be why I'm getting my BSOD. There's also a file browser in this distro and I can actually view all of my PC's drives and all of my data, so while I can't boot, and while gparted reports my entire drive is unallocated, my installation isn't totally corrupted.

**So my question is, how do I fix a no fake msdos table error?** While I'm reluctant to click it there is this option in gparted: `device > create partition table`

[image: create partition table]

If I click this, should that fix my BSOD? Note that I need to click 'yes' to the question "is this a GPT partition table?" in order to access gparted and the `create partition table` option. I'm not sure what `this` is referring to. Will selecting yes and clicking `create partition table` have any repercussions?

I also have a terminal in this distro. What commands can I run here to fix my BSOD: `no mountable boot volume`?

Comment: Before I or anyone else attempts to answer this question.  We need to make sure you have performed a backup of your most important files.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point,  I have indeed :)

Comment: "No fake msdos table That appears to be why I'm getting my BSOD" this is **not** why you are getting your BSOD. The lack of any partitions is why you are getting your BSOD. What were you trying to do exactly when this occurred?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq shrink my boot drive to create a partition to install ubuntu.  I also think you may be wrong, I do have partitions, I took care to mention I can see them and access my data. Even gparted can sort of see my partitions, I.e GPT signatures, however lack of a fake msdos table prevents my PC booting. This is all guess work on my part of course, but I can see my partitions so I do think youve got it wrong. my partitions exist. really hoping that notification would be an answer. you can see the error message.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq well why don't you tell me how to get my partitions back then?

Comment: Your screenshot shows no partitions. The fake msdos table is quite literally fake - it should have nothing to do with booting unless your PC is misconfigured. You can fix it by using gdisk or parted from the command line if you insist on it though.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486556/no-partitions-found-while-installing-dual-boot-win8-ubuntu-14-04 - this may work **IF** you were using MBR and not GPT to begin with. If you were using GPT, it will **destroy your data even more**. If you don't understand what this means, do `sudo parted -l` as suggested in the other question.